# No parameterless constructor defined for this object error in asp.net web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I get this error when trying to run my web service, WizardService.asmx:

```
System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.CreateServerInstance()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

Here is my web service code in C#

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.tempuri.com/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class WizardService : WebService
{
    private EventLog eventLog;

    private WizardService()
    {
        eventLog = new EventLog("EktronWizardServiceLog", "localhost", "EktronWizardService");
    }
```

Everywhere I have looked online (including this site) seems to indicate this error message has something to do with MVC, but I am not using MVC.  This is an ASMX .Net 4.5 web service.

Comment: You have to use the public default constructor for the serialization

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `private` parameter less constructor which is not accessible outside the class. Make the construct `public` so that it could be accessed outside the class for constructing objects of `WizardService`.

```
public WizardService()
{
    eventLog = new EventLog("EktronWizardServiceLog", "localhost", "EktronWizardService");
}
```

**[Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)**

**public** The type or member can be accessed by any other code in the same assembly or another assembly that references it.

**private** The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or struct.

**protected** The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or struct, or in a class that is derived from that class.

**internal** The type or member can be accessed by any code in the same assembly, but not from another assembly.

You can read more about access modifiers [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

**Problem :** You have declared your Constructor with `private` access modifier. so it is not accessible outside the class to construct the objects.

**Solution :** You should have `public` access modifier for the constructors  tobe accessed  from outside the class to construct the Objects.

Replace This:

```
private WizardService()
```

With This:

```
public WizardService()
```